# Django Setup:TypeError: 'pub_date' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Tags: django, migration

I am facing the error bellow, during the django setup

> raise TypeError("'%s' is an invalid keyword argument for this function" % list(kwargs)[0])
>   TypeError: 'pub_date' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

**Models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible
import datetime
from django.utils import timezone

# Create your models here.

class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

class Choice(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

@python_2_unicode_compatible  # only if you need to support Python 2
class Question(models.Model):
    # ...
    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

@python_2_unicode_compatible  # only if you need to support Python 2
class Choice(models.Model):
    # ...
    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text

class Question(models.Model):
    # ...
    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have blindly copy pasted from here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial02/. You need to read the tutorial properly. So what you need to do is rewrite your `models.py` like this:

```
from django.db import models

class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```